# nested javascript array to php array

Tags: javascript, php, arrays, json

I have a javascript array :
`disharray = ([aa,11,],[bb,22])`

I send this to php as a json object using - `var jsoncvrt = JSON.stringify(disharray);`

How do I extract the value of the nested arrays so that I can access values like:
`$a = aa` and `$b = 11`?

I use the below code but get the output as

```
aa11
bb22
```

Please note, my server uses php 5.2

```
$data = json_decode(stripcslashes($_POST['strings']));
foreach ($data as $d => $v) {
    foreach ($v as $v1 => $value) {
        echo $value;
    }
}
```

Comment: can you post a `var_dump` of `$data` ?

Comment: array(4) { [0]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "aa" [1]=> string(2) "11" } [1]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "bb" [1]=> string(2) "22" } [2]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "cc" [1]=> string(2) "33" } [3]=> array(2) { [0]=> string(2) "dd" [1]=> string(2) "44" }}

Comment: for what all this code? `$d=json_decode($_POST['str'],1);` `$d[0][1]==11`, `$d[1][0]=='bb'`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code is fine. Just add this at the top of the code

```
  $values = array();
```

Now change the inner `foreach` loop to

```
 if( sizeof($v) == 2 ){
    $values[$v[0]] = intval($v[1]);
 }
```

Now to access, say the value corresponding to 'aa' just use `$values['aa']`

You can insert it into a table using the following code

```
  $con = mysqli_connect(HOSTNAME, USERNAME, PASSWORD, DBNAME);
  $query = "INSERT INTO tablename (key, value) VALUES(?, ?);";
  $stmt = $con->prepare($query); 
  if( $stmt ){
       foreach ($values as $key => $value){
            $stmt->bind_param("sd", $key, $value);
            $stmt->execute();
       }
       $stmt->close();  
  }
  $con->close();
```

In the `$query` variable, the '?' stands for wild card character that can take any value and it is set by calling `bind_param()` function. In the `bind_param` function, the 's' stands for **string** and the 'd' stands for **integer** data type. This is the right way to execute database queries as they void the possibility of SQL Injections.

Comment: Thanks @sanketh, this works as well. Please read the comment i added on the above answer. Can you help me with that?

Comment: To answer your question, yes, it is possible to store these key value pairs in a database. There are apis in php inorder to connect to databases and run queries etc. The quite popular ones are `mysqli` and `PDO` for `mysql` engine.Read about them. I can't do much without you knowing something about them.

Comment: I'm using simple sql statement - INSERT INTO child_dish (dish_name,dish_price,F_id) VALUES ('$v','$v[0]', '$extra')" How do i get these two values using your code. Sorry i am learning PHP :)

Comment: Thanks a ton @sanketh . Your explanation was very precise :) and ur solution is perfect